# Accessing NODE_ENV at runtime in the server.js configuration of Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I find myself not able to access the NODE_ENV variable when trying to make config changes in the `config/server.js` file of Sails.js. I want to configure the `serverOptions` flag of the `express` property and bind ssl certificates - but only for production.

Assuming I started the server with `node app.js --prod`

This doesn't work:

```
module.exports = { ... };
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // undefined
```

But this does work:

```
module.exports = { ... };
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // production
}, 1000);
```

Basically all I want to do is:

```
module.exports = (function () {
  var env = process.env.NODE_ENV,
    ret = { express: {} };

  if (env == 'production') {
    ret.express.serverOptions = { key: ..., cert: ... };
  }

  return ret;
}());
```

I've seen similar answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152780/986408 but I can't understand how they should work when mine doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

run your application like this instead:

```
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

or

```
sails lift --prod
```

in the application root directory. the command line switch you're trying to use is meant to be passed to the sails executable, not directly to your application javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm gonna check it out the day after tomorrow. Would this also work for forever? Like `forever start app.js --prod`?

Comment: you would need to do `NODE_ENV=production forever start app.js`

Comment: `sails lift --prod` did not work for me, again wasn't able to access it, but your first suggestion worked very well!